# How do i change the path of executable?

Tags: linux, path

I am trying to change the executable path of OpenSSL from '/usr/bin/openssl' to '/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl'. I have tried

```
export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl:$PATH
```

but the `which openssl` command still gives me '/usr/bin/openssl'

How can I make the other openssl run without replacing the openssl in '/usr/bin/openssl'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

../bin/openssl is not a directory.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/openssl/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: that was pretty dumb of me :(

Comment: I get that this adds the other executable to path but how does it guarantee that one gets run instead of /usr/bin/openssl?

Answer: whichever is first in path
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413493/choosing-between-multiple-executables-with-same-name-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

Executables under /usr/bin are mostly symlinks to the original file. Could you please first check whether /usr/bin/openssl is a symlink with

```
ls -l /usr/bin/openssl
```

If it is a symlink (and probably it is), you can delete this symlink (noting the path it directs to for future reference. You can create a new link as such:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

If the /usr/bin/openssl is itself an executable, you can do:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl2
```

and repeat the symlink creation command above. This way, any references that point to the absolute path would not be broken.

Answer (score 0):

> > How can I make the other openssl run without replacing the openssl in `/usr/bin/openssl`?

You can edit the path, as @IporSircer says.  You can also fully qualify the name to the executable every time, e.g. call:

```
$ /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl
```

instead of

```
$ openssl
```